# asp:Image width attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

I am trying to get the width in pixels of a an asp:Image. The image is not local.

```
imgUserThumb.Width.Value
```

Is always coming back as 0.0 anyone know why? Or perhaps thats not the right way?
Also the image is using an "onerror" attribute to check if the image URL passed to it is valid, if not then it displays a default thumbnail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you not set width and height for the image tag, you will get 0.

if you need to get actual size of image, load it to bitmap and get the width from there.

```
Image img = new Bitmap("Mytest.png");
var imgwidth = img.Width;
```

### EDIT from URL

```
private  int GetImageWidth(string url)
{
    int width = 0;
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("name", "pw");
        byte[] imageBytes = client.DownloadData(url);
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(imageBytes))
        {
            var img = Image.FromStream(stream);
            width=  img.Width;
        }
    }
    return width;
}
```

Comment: Can I give it an URL to the image or it has to be local?